# C# MVC DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a drop down list for gender (gender.cshtml) in between my index.cshtml and welcome.cshtml page how do I do that. Another question is when some one selects their gender in the gender.cshtml page how can i make it show up in the welcome.cshtml page . For example if someone selects male, it shoud show up as WELCOME "the name entered in the index textbox" who is a MALE.

**HomeController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data.Entity;
using Newproject.Models;

namespace Newproject.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Gender()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Welcome(string SearchString)
    {  
        ViewBag.Name = SearchString;
        return View();
    } 
  } 
  }
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
 @{

ViewBag.Title = "Welcome";

}

    <br />
    @Html.Label("Name")
   <br />
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Welcome", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.TextBox("SearchString");
 <input id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" placeholder="test" type="submit" value="Search" />
    }
```

**USER.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Newproject.Models
{
public class User
{
    public string SearchString { get; set; }
}
}
```

**Gender.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Newproject.Models
{
public class Gender    
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
}
```

**Gender.cshtml**

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Gender";
}

<h2>Gender</h2>
```

**Welcome.cshtml**

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Welcome";
string CustNo = ViewBag.Name;
}


   <p>Welcome @CustNo</p>
```

Comment: What does this "in between my index.cshtml and welcome.cshtml page" even mean?

Comment: Where *exactly* do you want this dropdown list?

Comment: In between the index view page and welcome view page as shown in homecontroller.cs,  just a drop down list with male and female and when the customer selects what gender he/she is it showed be carried over to the welcome view page using session

Comment: i want the drop down list in gender.cshtml page and when submit is clicked it should be carried over to welcome page using session

Answer (score 0):

You can use a view model to transfer data between your view(s) and action method(s). view model is just a simple POCO class.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
public class WelcomeVm
{
  public string Name {set;get;}
  public string Gender {set;get;}
  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Genders {set;get;}
}
```

Now in your Gender GET action,create an object of this, load `Genders` property and send to the view

```
public ActionResult Gender()
{
  var vm = new WelcomeVm();
  vm.Genders = new List<SelectListItem>{
      new SelectListItem { Value="Male", Text="Male"},
      new SelectListItem { Value="FeMale", Text="FeMale"}
  };
  return View(vm);
}
```

In your Gender view

```
@model WelcomeVm
@using(Html.BeginForm("Welcome","YourControllerNameHere"))
{
  <label>Name </label>
  @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.Name)
  <label>Gender</label>
  @Html.DropDownListFor(s=>sGender,Model.Genders)
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

Now in your Welcome action method, you can use the same view model as the parameter type so that model binding works perfectly and map the posted form data to an object of this class.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Welcome(WelcomeVm model)
{
  return View(model);
}
```

and in the `Welcome.cshtml` razor view, simply display it

```
@model WelcomeVm
<p>Hello @Model.Name who is a @Model.Gender</p>
```

Comment: public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Genders { set; get; }

Comment: it says the type of namespace name 'SelectListItem' could not be found( are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: `SelectListItem` belongs to `System.Web.Mvc` namespace. You need to include that with a using statement. See my updated answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38355180/c-sharp-mvc-dropdownlist-errors

Comment: Why are you posting another question with the same problem ? Did you try this answer and did it solve the problem you had ?